# Removing AM | PM from date variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to trim out the AM|PM to get a difference between two datetime in minutes?

However, when I run my code I get errors (NaN minutes), how do I safely remove the `AM | PM` ?

Here is my Code

```
var startTime = $('.startcall').val(); //08/22/2018 1:34 PM
var endTime = $('.endcall').val(); //08/22/2018 1:54 PM

startTime = new Date(startTime.replace(/([0-9]{4}) .{3}/, '$1'));

endTime = new Date(endTime.replace(/([0-9]{4}) .{3}/, '$1'));

console.log(startTime);
console.log(endTime);

var difference = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
var resultInMinutes = Math.round(difference / 60000);

$('.callduration').val(resultInMinutes + ' minutes');
```

Comment: Please exchange `$('.startcall').val();` for actual values from the input field. Is it an `input type="date"` or just text?

Comment: @Luca its  a text input

Comment: removing AM | PM is not necessary, Date constructor can take them in. What if a french use your site ? I would never add an AM | PM so you should look for that. And a last one What's is the duration in minute of a call between `11:59 AM` and `0:01 PM` with AM | PM it is `2 minutes` without it is `12hours and 2minutes`

Comment: with the value you added for example : `new Date("08/22/2018 1:54 PM")` is valid there is no need for transformation

Comment: hello @jonatjano., i'm getting NaN minutes.... something is wrong

Comment: it worked! I added    startTime = new Date(startTime); endTime = new Date(endTime);

Comment: @jonatjano is right, you should not change the format like that, beside the fact that it'll be invalid date/time to compare and diff with another, even after making it work you'll get a wrong result in some cases,

you should use a 24H format and compare those, or just use localized time format

Comment: @jonatjano I'm not sure but I don't think `0:01 PM` is valid, and should be either `12:01 AM` or `12:01 PM` - `12:01 AM` could also be `00:01` without the designator.

Comment: @phuzi to be honest I had to test and even now I'm not sure, a date created using `0:01 PM` will have the same value than a date created using `12:01 PM`. As I said in my first comment I'm not english speaker and my local format for time does not use `AM | PM` I'm not even sure which one is morning so I may say invalid things when using it :p. IMHO `24h` system seem easier

Comment: @phuzi I'd add that the problem is the same even if you take `11:59 AM` and `01:01 PM` when you remove `AM` and `PM` JS read the hours using `24h format`

Comment: @jonatjano As a native english speaker (from the UK) we would never use `0:01 AM` always `12:01 AM` when using 12h format.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved, for anyone that comes by again in the future, I had to set my variables as date here is the final code;

```
var startTime = $('.startcall').val();
    var endTime = $('.endcall').val();

    startTime = new Date(startTime);

    endTime = new Date(endTime);;

    console.log(startTime);
    console.log(endTime);

    var difference = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
    var resultInMinutes = Math.round(difference / 60000);

    $('.callduration').val(resultInMinutes + ' minutes');
```